# Как вставить в span данные из элемента? (цена в блоке должна по клику вставляться в span)

Tags: javascript

1. У нас есть элементы с разными ценами - `$79 / $55 / $35 / $25`
   (например)
2. Кликая на элемент с ценой, цена которая находиться в этом блоке
   переносится в `span`
3. Кликая на следующий блок, цена которая находиться в этом блоке
   переносится в этот же `span`, но предыдущая цена удаляется

По сути цена будет постоянно меняться.

```
let list = document.querySelector('#list');
    let item = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

    list.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let price = [79, 59, 49, 29];
        let result = document.getElementById('result');

        let target = e.target;

        if (target.classList.contains('item')) {
            Object.keys(item).map((i) => {
                item[i].classList.remove('item--active');
            });
        }

        target.classList.add('item--active');

        for (let itemPrice of price) {
            result.innerHTML = `${itemPrice}`;
            console.log(itemPrice);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Заголовок должен содержать краткую суть проблемы, а не крик души об абстрактной проблеме.. Вопрос должен содержать минимальный  воспроизводимый пример и описание конечного желаемого результата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.textContent = target.textContent;
```

Comment: @PavelDzemidovich что, в таком случае, удерживает Вас от щелчка по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа?